Plot with Arrows in the X and Y axes
I want to plot a figure such that there is an arrow to the right of the x-axis and two arrows at the top and bottom of the y -axis. Also the x-axis should be at the right hand side.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create some sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# Create the figure and axis objects
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# Plot the data
ax.plot(x, y)

# Remove the top and right spines
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

# Add arrows to the y-axis
#ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

# Add arrowheads
#

# Set labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
#ax.set_title('Plot with Arrows on Y-axis')

# Display the plot
plt.show()



Could you potentially add an image of the graph you are trying to create, or at the very least rephrase your question?

I think this question will be closed since it is a duplicate but I am posting an answer anyway because I just used the same on one of my plots.
So you can use ax.annotate for this as in
ax.annotate('', xy=(max(np.log(t)), 0), xytext=(max(np.log(t))-0.0001, 0), 
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle='->', lw=1))   # you should change the coordinates according to your data on the x-axis

